# Подстраиваем высоту блока под замощение фоновым изображением

Tags: jquery, html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, с небольшим JQuery костылем :)

В JQuery слаб, но стараюсь учиться :)

Итак, есть кусочек контента:

```
<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Pellentesque vitae pharetra velit.
</div>
```

Его фоновое изображение требует замощения по вертикали (колечки переплета книги). Высота фонового изображения 48px (в примере). Поскольку высота блока не известна, последняя картинка при замощении может быть как угодна обрезанна (по горизонтали). Следовательно, для хорошего замощения, высота блока должна быть кратна выосте картинки в 48px. Допускается добавить несколько пикселей высоты этом блоку, чтобы получить значение кратное 48px.

Хочется реализовать такой алгоритм:

1. Выводим блок с неизвестной высотой
2. Получаем высоту
3. Добавляем к высоте недостающие до следущего, кратного 48px значения, пиксели
4. Устанавливаем высоту

Моя первая версия: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUFHS/).

```
(function() {
    var content = $('.content');
    var contentHeight = content.height();

    contentHeight = contentHeight + ( 48 - (contentHeight % 48 ) );
    content.height(contentHeight);

})();
```

Код работает, но

1. Отрабатывает однократно при загрузке страницы. Если пользователь уменьшит ширину, то физическая высота блока увеличится, а установленное CSS значение останется. Видимо в код надо добавить отслеживание события изменения (чего не ясно) и перевыполнять этот код.
2. Не уверен в правильности написания кода. Думаю надо отказатсья от переменных. Ведь если мы хотим отслеживать какие-то изменения, это должно происходить с оригинальным объектом $('content'), верно? Т.е. должно быть что-то вроде:

.

```
(function()
    $('.content').height(
        $(this).height + ( 48 - ($(this).height % 48 ) );
    );    
})();
```

Но такой код работает :(

**UPD:** решение [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUFHS/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если однократно отрабатывает правильно, то создайте из этого функцию и используйте событие [resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). Должно получить что-то такого типа

```
function name(){
//сама функция
}
name();
$(window).resize(name);
```

Это навскидку, просто направление, мог что-то пропустить в синтаксисе.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. Думаю в моем случае изменения высоты могут быть только из-за изменения ширины окна. Это то, что нужно. А если мыслить более обще: например динамическая подгрузка текста в этот блок, то от чего тогда оттолкнуться?

Comment: Смотря что необходимо. 
Для конкретной задачи есть конкретное решение.

Comment: Получилось со второго разу:
http://jsfiddle.net/mUFHS/2/
В слепую превратить в функцию не удалось :)
Еще раз спасибо :)